# Visual StudioのGoogleTestがDebugモードの時だけ検出されない

Tags: c++, visual-studio, テスト

VS2019のdllを対象にしたGoogleTestでDebugモードを選択しているときのみテストエクスプローラーにテストが表示されなくなります
Releaseモードでは問題なくテストケースが表示され、実行も可能です
GoogleTestプロジェクトを作成するときは「GoogleTestの使用方法」を「ダイナミックライブラリ」で、「C++ランタイムライブラリ」は「スタティックライブラリ(推奨)」を選択して作成しています

コードは以下の通りです

```
//main.cpp
#include "header.h"
void MyClass::hello() {
    std::cout << "hello" << std::endl;
}

//header.h
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class __declspec(dllexport) MyClass {
public:
    MyClass() {};
    void hello();
};
//test.cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include "../header.h"

TEST(TestCaseName, TestName) {
    MyClass my = MyClass();
    my.hello();
  EXPECT_EQ(1, 1);
  EXPECT_TRUE(true);
}
```

### 更新

問題が再現するソリューションをGithubにアップロードしました
https://github.com/hajime-te/Project2

Visual Studioのスクショも添付します
[image: Releaseモードでテストが表示されている]
[image: Debugモードに切り替えるとテストが見えなくなる]

### 再更新

環境の情報を記載します
Windows10 1903
Visual Studio Professional 2019 Ver 16.5.2
Google TestのNugetパッケージ 
Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn V1.8.1.3

### 再再々更新

Visual Studioの出力ウィンドウで「テスト」タブがありましたので、そちらを確認するとエラーメッセージが確認できましたので添付します
test.exeがテスト実行ファイル、target.dllがテスト対象のdllファイルになります

```
'Test.exe' のデバッグ シンボルが見つかりませんでした。'--list_content' 探索を使用するには、デバッグ シンボルが使用可能であることを確認するか、.runsettings ファイルによって '<ForceListContent>' を使用します。
Test Adapter for Google Test: テストの検出を開始しています...
テストの検出が完了しました。全体の期間: 00:00:00.2503856
target.dll Test.exe で使用できるテストはありません。テスト探索プログラムおよび実行プログラムが登録されており、プラットフォームおよびフレームワークのバージョン設定が適切であることを確認してから、もう一度お試しください。
========== テスト検出が完了しました: 4.6 秒 に 0 件のテストが見つかりました ==========
```

これを確認して、2つのプロジェクトのプロパティを確認しましたが一致しておりました
- ターゲットプラットフォームバージョン: 10.0.18362.0
- プラットフォーム: x64
- プラットフォームツールセット: Visual Studio 2015 (v140)

Comment: ソリューション&プロジェクト全体を何処かに格納してリンクしてもらった方が良いかもしれません。それからどんな手順で作業して何がどうおかしいのかの説明と、最後のおかしい部分のスクリーンショットがあると、問題への理解が早くなると思われます。

Comment: 不足があるかもしれませんが、githubにプロジェクトをアップロードして、テストエクスプローラーのスクショを添付しました。作業手順は本文中のテストプロジェクト作成とサンプルコードの記述になります

Comment: `Test.exe`や`target.dll`は元々の問題が出たプロジェクトですか？ githubに上げられた`Project2`の中には存在しないようですが。その辺の細かい名前や設定が統一されていなくて、本来必要な名前・設定と変わってしまっている可能性も考えられます。

Comment: Githubに挙がっている再現環境のプロジェクトになりますが、フルパスで表示されてしまったため代替テキストを使用していたことを記述しておりませんでした。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

何かの試行錯誤の結果かもしれませんが、テスト対象の`Project2`プロジェクトのプロパティでおかしなところがあります。

- `Win32`の`Debug`モードの時に、`プラットフォームツールセット`が`Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`になっています。
  他は`Visual Studio 2019 (v142)`です。
- `Win32`の`Release`モードの時に、`構成の種類`が`アプリケーション (.exe)`になっています。
  他は`ダイナミック ライブラリ (.dll)`です。

なお、`プラットフォームツールセット`の`Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`は、`Visual Studio 2015 (v140) (インストールされていません)`かもしれません。

これらを他と合わせるようにしてみたら、何か状況に変化があるかもしれません。

`プラットフォームツールセット`を`Visual Studio 2019 (v142)`に、`構成の種類`を`ダイナミック ライブラリ (.dll)`に統一する。

---

そういえば、テストエクスプローラーのデザインが違うのですが、使っているエディションの違いとかあるのでしょうか？あるいは設定しているテーマの関係かもしれませんが。
当方はWindows用のVisual Studio Community 2019で、こんな画面です。
[image: テストエクスプローラー画像]

当方でプラットフォームツールセットと構成の種類を統一した状況では、Debugモードかどうかにかかわりなく、Debug/Release,x86/x64のどれでも何か構成を変更した後にテストエクスプローラーを起動して「実行」(左から2つ目の緑色の▶)や「直前の実行の繰り返し」(左から3つ目の丸に沿った矢印に囲まれた緑色の▶)をクリックすると、質問にあったような以下の表示になります。
[image: テストエクスプローラーエラー画像]

上記が発生した状態で「すべてのテストを実行」(左端の陰付き緑色の▶)をクリックすると、ビルドとテストが実行されて正常にテストのツリーが表示された状態になります。
**それ以後はDebug/Release,x86/x64の構成を変更せずにいれば「実行」「直前の実行の繰り返し」を行うことが出来ます。**

そうした動作そのものが何か問題なのでしょうか？ あるいはプラットフォームツールセットと構成の種類を統一した状況でもそういう動作にならないとか？

---

当方の版数は以下です。WindowsとVisualStudioの版数がちょっと違いますね。

Windows10 1909
Visual Studio Community 2019 Ver 16.6.0
Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn V1.8.1.3

---

当方では、GitHubで提示されたソリューション＆プロジェクトを、更新された以下の情報で設定して問題無くコンパイル・テストが実行されています。

> - ターゲットプラットフォームバージョン: 10.0.18362.0
> - プラットフォーム: x64
> - プラットフォームツールセット: Visual Studio 2015 (v140)

他に何か試すとしたら、以下のような点くらいでしょうか。

- Visual Studio自身の起動を「管理者として実行」で行ってみる
- Visual Studio InstallerにてVisual Studioを「修復」してみる
- Visual Studio InstallerにてVisual Studioを最新版(16.6.1)に「更新」してみる
- Visual Studio Installerの「更新」でC++関連の個別のコンポーネントを指定して最新のものにしてみる
- Windows10を1909や、あるいは2004(May 2020 Update)まで更新してみる

Comment: 元々VS2019でVS2015のランタイムを使用してビルドできるかどうかの検証中に発生したトラブルで、その検証作業中の跡が残っておりました
プラットフォームツールセットと構成の種類を統一しても状況に変化ありませんでした

Comment: 使用しているエディションはVS2019 Professionalです
私の環境では、Debugモードの場合のみ2枚目の画像で「すべてのテストを実行」をクリックしても1枚目の画像のようにならず2枚目の画像の状態のままです
Releaseモードでは添付していただいた画像の通りになります

Comment: あと他にはVSの版数(16.6.0)とGoogleTestの版数(1.8.1.3)とか、VSのインストールしているワークロード/コンポーネント/拡張機能等の差でしょうか。さらにはOSのUpdateも含めて最新に上げてあるかとか。その辺でも変わらないならちょっとわからない状況ですね。

Comment: 開発環境のバージョンなどを記述しました

Comment: 返信が遅くなり申し訳ありません。Visual Studioを最新版にアップロードすることで問題が解決しました